# non-existence of sentence that captured specific property

Tags: first-order-logic

> For a sentence $\varphi$, we'll define $Spec(\varphi)$ to be the set of all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which there is a model $M$ with $|D^M|=n$, such that $M\models\varphi$. 
> Let $\Sigma=\{P(\cdot),R(\cdot)\}$, where $P,\,R\,$ are relations.
>
>  $\boldsymbol{Disprove:} $ There is a sentence $\psi$ above $\Sigma$ such that $Spec(\psi)=\{n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}_{odd} \}$.

I have a disproof, but I wonder if part of it is unnecessary. 
This is the disproof I have which got all the points (the question taken from an exam): 
Assume by contradiction that such $\psi$ exists. Because $1$ is an odd number, there is a model $M$, with $|D^M|=1$ such that $M\models\psi$. Without loss of generality let $D^M=\{a\}$. 
Define a new model, $M'$, such that: $D^{M'}=\{a,b\}$ and the next holds: 
$\{a\}\in R^M \iff \{a,b\}\in R^{M'}$ 
 $\{a\}\in P^M \iff \{a,b\}\in P^{M'}$ 
$M'$ is an expansion of $M$. We will define an equivalence relation, $\boldsymbol{\sim}$, with respect to the relations $P,R$. Namely, $\boldsymbol{\sim}$ will have four equivalance classes: as the number of options to be in $P$ or $R$. 
 By the way $M$ defines $P$ and $R$, there is only one equivalence class, which is: $\{a,b\}$. Let $[\bar{a}]$ be it's representor. 
Now we will define an additional model, $N$, as follow: $D^N$ will contain the representatives of the equivalence classes of $\boldsymbol{\sim}$ with respect to $M$. $N$ will define the realtions $P$ and $R$ as follows: 
$\{a,b\}\in R^{M'}\iff \{\bar{a}\}\in R^N$ 
 $\{a,b\}\in P^{M'}\iff \{\bar{a}\}\in P^N$ 
So we actually have:
$M'\models\psi \iff N\models\psi$ 
From transitivity we have: 
$\{a\}\in R^M \iff \{\bar{a}\}\in R^N$ 
$\{a\}\in R^M \iff \{\bar{a}\}\in P^N$ 
Namley $N$ is isomorphic to $M$, and becuase $M\models\psi$ we have due to isomorphism $N\models\psi$ which is contradiction, $|D^N|$ is an even number (2).

My question is: wasn't it sufficient to show that $M\models\psi \iff M'\models\psi\,\,$? 
Or the whole reason for defining $N$ was because we can't show the above?
I can't really understand what $N$ was needed for.

Would appreciate help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that $N$ is used in this way. If you want a proof without $N$, you will have to prove in some other way (for example, by  sentence induction) that $M'\models\psi$.

I understand you that it is very intuitive why $M'\models\psi$, but sadly formalism doesn't care about intuition, so we need a rigorous proof.

Comment: Got it, thank you! :)